# Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules. How can i resolve it?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is the output:

```
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$InputEventMask found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$ListSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabLayoutPolicy found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderJustification found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderTitlePosition found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TreeSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Pattern found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormat found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormatPattern found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.RegExp found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Subst found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
```

I tried

```
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
     compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
 }
```

but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is as follows.

```
configurations { implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations' }
```

You can put the above code in the android{} of the app level gradle.

It worked for me.